# How can I make a popup box but in the same window?

Tags: php, javascript, sql-server

I am building a website and have no knowledge of any computer language and I need help making a box appear when I click on an image or link with a game inside it, kind of like a popup in the same window in the centre of the page over everything with the background darker or covered with a grey translucent box. So please tell me how I could do this to make my desire successful and this would be a great help!

Comment: Sounds like you want a [lightbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_(JavaScript)) or some other kind of [modal dialog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window).

Comment: Try [Redips JavaScript Dialog Box](http://www.redips.net/javascript/dialog-box/). It's easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

With little knowledge of any computer language, I suggest using jQuery (or hiring a [contractor](http://www.vworker.com/)).  There are plenty of examples here - http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

After implementing the jQuery library, if you need further assistance, ask a new question with your sample code and I'm sure someone will be able to help out.

Answer (score 0):

yes chris is absolutely right. you can use frameworks like 
jquery and mootools to make an interactive pop up box

the pop up box is generally know as a lightbox. 
you can use the plugins like dialog

[Dialog - Jquery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

or 
You can read some tutorials on how to do it here
[the best source to learn jquery via tutorials](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/11/hovering-gallery-css3-jquery/)